# Multiplying elements in a module by -1

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring (commutative for my purposes, if that matters) and $M$ be an $R$-module, with binary operation $*:R\text{ X }M \to M$. Is it true, in general, that:

$(-1)*x=-x$, $x\in M$

That is, is the additive inverse of $1$ times $x$ equal to the additive inverse of $x$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because (1) the associativity rule and the meaning of the additive inverse:

$$x+(-1)\cdot x=(1+(-1))\cdot x=0\cdot x=0$$

and since also $\;x+(-x)=0\;$ (as above), then by uniqueness of inverses in general abelian groups:

$$\begin{cases}x+(-1)x=0\\{}\\x+(-x)=0\end{cases}\;\;\;\;\implies -x=(-1)x$$